# Angular custom provider depends on another custom provider

Tags: angular, domain-driven-design, angular-providers

I have a service that implements `IDatabase` interface and save data using Firebase (for example). I wanted that it will be replaceable with another service that will implement `IDatabase` interface (couchDb for example). And a couple of repository services (depends on data type) will use this root db service.

So I decided to use angular custom providers:

Here I created an **APP_DB** `Injection Token` that related to IDatabase interface.

```
export const APP_DATA_DB = new InjectionToken<IDatabase>('app-data-delta-db');
```

Then I used this token for declaring root DB service that will be available in all submodules of application.

```
 // app.module.ts:

    @NgModule({
       providers: [{ provide: APP_DB, useClass: AppDataFirebaseService }]
```

And in one of the submodules (`users-repository.module`) I used also custom provider for repository module using `useFactory` option:

```
//users-repository.module.ts:

    @NgModule({
        providers: [
        {    provide: USERS_REPOSITORY_SERVICE,
             useFactory: (appDb: IDatabase, store: Store<any>) => {
                 return new VehicleRepositoryService(appDb, store),
             deps: [APP_DB, Store]
        }]
```

But when I am looking on imports at the top of users-repository.module.ts, I see that I import APP_DB from it's file where the service of "Firbase" sits.

**And a question is** how I will change a root DB service to `CouchDb` service by `useClass` in the `app.module.ts` when the injection token in all submodules points to **APP_DB** from `Firestore` service?

Answer (score 0):

I think the APP_DB should be re-provided in the users-repository.module.ts or deeper, at the level of a component tha use it. So in this way you will be able to use more specific implementation of that service (possible you shall change your architecture a little bit). Please consider to check the next article: [Hierarchical Dependency Injectors](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection).